# Using kotlin-stdlib 1.1.51 but kotlin-runtime 1.3 is loaded

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I use kotlin-1.1.51 with gradle, but kotlin-runtime-1.1.3 is loaded
Environment:

- Windows10
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2.5

[build.gradle](https://github.com/C6H2Cl2/MCDevNightSample/blob/master/build.gradle)
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJr1.png)

Comment: Can you show output from `./gradlew depI  --configuration compile --dependency kotlin-runtime` please? Seems like one of the dependencies has promoted to the higher version

Comment: this is the [output](https://pastebin.com/RksLK2dc).

Comment: From output I see version `1.1.3`  was promoted by your dependency Forgelin, I found that it actually [use it](https://github.com/shadowfacts/Forgelin/blob/master/gradle.properties). Is there a good reason why do you want to use older version of kotlin?

Comment: No, I want to use the latest version of kotlin.
but, using forgelin is the best way to use kotlin for minecraft-modding

Comment: kotlin runtime has been [officially deprecated](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime) you _can try_ to include runtime dependency using the same version as you wish `compile group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: I tried it and I succeed to overwrite version of kotlin-runtime.
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I have posted answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to enforce version of `kotlin-runtime` to one used in project `1.1.51`

```
compile group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:$kotlin_version"
```